# Setting titleView of UINavigationItem makes titleView disappear

Tags: ios, swift

I've set the `titleView` of a `UIViewController`'s `navigationItem` after `init()`. After pushing the VC to `UINavigationController`, `titleView` appears correctly at first time. But when I change (re-set) a `titleView` to an other view, it suddenly disappears.

But when I push another  view controller and navigate back, it suddenly appears.
Do I have to perform any actions after re-setting the `titleView`?

Comment: Try changing/placing the logic  it in the `viewDidAppear`

Comment: When you say "after init()", where exactly are you setting the title? Can you show us some code?

Answer (score -1):

If you are not using tab bar controller, then in **viewDidLoad**
setting the title as **self.title** is better.I have mentioned Tab bar Controller because if you have a view controller (in a NavigationController) in a UITabBarController, then if you set self.title it overrides the name of the tab as well as the top title.

Answer (score -2):

I think you maybe code like this:
    `self.navigationItem.titleView = self.yourView;`
If your yourView is a custom class , it maybe remove from superView when you switch your viewcontroller to next one;
So code like this maybe solve your problem:
    `[self.navigationItem.titleView addSubview:yourView];`

Comment: This has nothing to do weather your title view is a custom view or not. `titleVew`of `UINavigationItem` is a strong property. It will keep the title view as long as the navigation item is kept. Furthermore `titleView` is `nil`if you doen't set it. Thus, your last statement will do nothing.

Comment: Yes , but if its a custom view , he maybe rewrite the func removeFromSuperView , use addSubview is better on this time;And when you set a titleview on stroyboard , its also a subview of titleView ; titleView need init is right , i think we both know it.

Comment: The question is "Do I have to perform any actions after re-setting the titleView?", and i just give him a better choose to avoid problems , am i wrong anywhere? please tell me :)